# Yii 2 Running a Cron in the basic template

Tags: cron, yii2

I have seen instructions on running a cron in the advanced template, but cant figure out how to do it on the basic template. I have the following controller in the basic controllers folder.

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use yii\console\Controller;

/**
 * Cron controller
 */
class CronController extends Controller {

    public function actionIndex() {
        echo "cron service runnning";
    }

    public function actionMail($to) {
        echo "Sending mail to " . $to;
    }

}
```

I have navigated to the root of my application and tried all these comands

```
yii cron
php yii cron
```

Im getting unknown comand "cron"

Comment: I figured it out. Have to put the CronController in the commands folder. sheesH!

Comment: You can post this as an answer in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but failed to find anyone with an actual answer to this.

If you look at the code for the Yii exec file you'll notice it requires /common/config/aliases.php file as well as console/config/main.php. You can naturally change these or copy over these from the advanced template.

Hope that solves the problem for anyone wanting to do the same thing.